# FirebaseAnalytics iOS Undefined symbols for x86 simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, analytics

This is my error message:

```
Showing Recent Messages
Undefined symbol: _APMUserDataFieldEmailAddress
```

```
Showing Recent Messages
Copied /Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator to Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/core-hjcudorpvsjsguggeuypowcrgdts/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/FirebaseAnalytics/AdIdSupport
```

Xcode: 14.0.1

Podfile:

```rb
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '12.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

workspace 'xxx.xcworkspace'

target 'xxx' do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'FirebaseAnalytics', '10.1.0'
    project './xxx/xxx.xcodeproj'
end
```

Intel based machine.

I've tried:

- Clean pods
- Clean derived data
- `FirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdId`
- Clean project run

Any thoughts?
I'll appreciate it!

Comment: same issue on my side. other firebase products are fine but analytics. none of the answers online worked for me. let us know if you find a solution.